# Accessing an external table from a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

```
Rails 3.2
```

I am using the API gem. What the client wants, is to keep the table where he wants to whitelist the email addresses that can be used to access the API, in a seprate table, that he only can access through phpmyadmin.

This would be a single table:

```
api_users
```

With a single column: email (in addition to id, created_at, updated_at)

The email addresses that would go in this table, also exist in the users table for the rails application.

If I create a model: models/api_user.rb:

```
class ApiUser< ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email
```

And, in my models/api_ability.rb, I add the following:

```
class ApiAbility
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user, params = {})
    user ||= User.new   
    if ApiUser.find_by_email(user.email)
      can :manage, :api
    end
  end

end
```

Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds absolutely doable. You might want to add something like

```
def readonly?
  true
end
```

to the `ApiUser` class to make sure no one will try to create instances of it from within Rails. But apart from that I don't see any reason not to do it that way given the clients requirements.

Comment: It would indeed be called `readonly?` which would be overriding an [existing method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/46f511685c91486295a418547bb08c2aa5e49cfc/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L483) from `ActiveRecord::Core`